# Ansible: Conditional Statement wierd Error

Tags: ansible, devops

Sorry for the really noobish question, I'm trying to learn better Ansible and I have this issue:
I have 3 CentOS Hosts and I try to make the first task fail, get the variable and if it is failed to run the next task.

```
---
- hosts: slaves
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: install httpd
      apt: name=apache2 state=latest
      register: result
      ignore_errors: true

    - name: install httpd again
      yum: name=httpd state=latest
      when: result|failed
```

However instead of successfuly working it I get:

```
fatal: [slave2]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'result|failed' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: no filter named 'failed'. String: {% if result|failed %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}\n\nThe error appears to be in '/private/etc/ansible/vars/Conditional': line 11, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: install httpd Again\n      ^ here\n"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I answered my own questions.
Seems that is no longer working, "result | failed", is now:

```
when: result is failed
```